# Algolia Instantsearch Integration in Shopify

Tags: e-commerce, shopify, algolia

In my shopify site, I have multiple facet search attributes like weight, price, color etc to be shown as slider with input box range in the algolia search UI. Is it possible to create a customized widget for a slider with range input box for a facet, or any other solutions to meet the requirements....Check out the below image for reference...

[image]

Comment: It will be best to contact the APP developers, since if I remember correctly the APP was using the `hogan.js` framework and it was a little all over the place.

Comment: I think this post on Algolia's discourse forum might be helpful: https://discourse.algolia.com/t/how-to-create-facet-widget-from-shopify-metafield/1710/ .

Comment: I have gone through this link before, you have mentioned the issue in implementing range slider for string values, I also need the solution for that too...

Comment: Another doubt whether its possible to include input range to slider widget, if possible it would be helpful if you could provide code or some examples...